# Mapbox Clustering without GeoJSON file

Tags: java, android, mapbox

how i can clustering markers with this method?
I wanted to make markers group in groups with the current method.

```
EasyDB stores = EasyDB.init(getActivity(), "Objects");
        stores.setTableName("Stores");
        Cursor res = stores.getAllData();
while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    String name = res.getString(5);
                    String lat = res.getString(8);
                    String lang = res.getString(9);
                    String desc = res.getString(4);
    mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .setIcon(icon)
                                        .position(point)
                                        .setSnippet(snipp)
                                        .title(id));

}
```

Comment: do you know the way to avoid geo json usage for clustering?

Answer (score 1):

Given the use of `MarkerOptions` here, it looks like you are using the [Mapbox Annotations plugin for Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/). If so, you will need to create a [GeoJSON object](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/geojson/) from the markers in your database so that you can use a [`GeoJsonOptions`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/9.1.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/sources/GeoJsonOptions.html) object to pass to a [`SymbolManager`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/plugin-annotation/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/annotation/SymbolManager.java) instance to enable clustering. For example, if you parse your data to a GeoJSON object and store it in a variable `geoJsonData`:

```
GeoJsonOptions geoJsonOptions = new GeoJsonOptions()
  .withCluster(true)
  .withClusterMaxZoom(14)
  .withClusterRadius(10);

symbolManager = new SymbolManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style, null, geoJsonOptions);
symbolManager.setIconAllowOverlap(true);

List<SymbolOptions> options = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < geoJsonData.length(); i++) {
  Feature feature = features.get(i);
  options.add(new SymbolOptions()
    .withGeometry((Point) feature.geometry())
    .withIconImage("name-of-icon-to-use-for-clusters")
  );
}
```

[This example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/clustering-on-top/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/ClusteringActivity.java) from the [Mapbox Android Plugins demo app](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/clustering-on-top) shows how to implement clustering with annotations.

Comment: I need to store my markers in an array?And turn this array into GeoJson?